# A way to know if a Blob object exists with Azure API

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to know if a blob file exists inside a container without getting the whole list of blob objects ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that I'm using

```
    public static bool Exists(this CloudBlob blob)
    {
        try
        {   
            blob.FetchAttributes();
            return true;
        }
        catch (StorageClientException e)
        {
            if (e.ErrorCode == StorageErrorCode.ResourceNotFound)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That probably comes from here: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/testing-existence-of-a-windows-azure-blob. :-) Also, it's in my [smarx.WasStorageExtensions NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/smarx.WazStorageExtensions).

Comment: Has this changed with SDK 1.7?

Comment: This is no longer relevant, since in SDK2.x (2.3) they have removed it. They made a complete shit out of the library!!!    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363564/windowsazure-storage-v2-storageexception is showing how to handle these exceptions, but the Error code is inside a prop, that is NULL most of the time, which will THROW an exception when you try to handle the code !!! The fall-back is to use the status codes! Great improvement, right? The new SDK is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

If you know the address of the blob, a tip from the Azure SDK is to first build a `CloudBlockBlob` (or a `CloudPageBlob`) and then call `FetchAttributes`. This call will throw a `StorageClientException` if it cannot locate the blob.

From the [`CloudBlobClient.GetBlockBlobReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872383) documentation:

> The FetchAttributes method executes a HEAD request to populate the
>   blob's properties and metadata and as such is a lightweight option for
>   determining whether the blob exists.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Windows Azure Storage Client Library 2.0, the blob contains method Exists(), e.g: `blob.Exists()`

the same is true for the `BlobContainer`.