# WindowsAzure.Storage v2 StorageException

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage

I'm migrating from WindowsAzure.StorageClient 1.7 to WindowsAzure.Storage 2.0, and I'm working right now on the management of the exceptions. Following this [guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-breaking-changes-amp-migration-guide.aspx) and other sources, I found out I had to migrate from

```
try
{
    // Something
}
catch (StorageClientException e)
{
    switch (e.ErrorCode)
    {
        case StorageErrorCode.ContainerNotFound:
        case StorageErrorCode.ResourceNotFound:
        case StorageErrorCode.BlobNotFound:
        case StorageErrorCode.ConditionFailed:
            // Do something
    }
}
```

to

```
try
{
    // Something
}
catch (StorageException e)
{
    switch (e.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorCode)
    {
        case StorageErrorCodeStrings.ContainerNotFound:
        case StorageErrorCodeStrings.ResourceNotFound:
        case BlobErrorCodeStrings.BlobNotFound:
        case StorageErrorCodeStrings.ConditionNotMet:
            // Do something
    }
}
```

Looks simple.
The problem is ExtendedErrorInformation is always equal to null. The HttpStatusMessage instead says 'The specified blob does not exist.', as it should.

I thought it was caused by the simulator of the test environment, but trying it in a real Azure environment drived me to the same situation.

Any idea?

Comment: According to the documentation, Extended Error Information should not be relied upon for code logic - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @RussCam that link seems to be about RPC, not the storage client API.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to look at the `RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode` instead. This seems to be more reliable anyway. Your code translates rather easily to:

```
try
{
    // Something
}
catch (StorageException e)
{
    switch (e.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode)
    {
        case (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
        case (int)HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed:
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I knew that status code, but it's way too much generic for my purposes. I needed the 'power' given by the error code strings of Azure, to take different actions. I managed to take the string from the HttpStatusMessage and comparing it with the Azure ones to return the code. @Gaurav in the other reply was correct, the problem is only with the FetchAttributes, for what I've seen.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried it and was surprised to see that indeed the ExtendedErrorInformation object is null. However it's not always null. For example, if I try to create a blob container which already exists using blobContainer.Create() method, I will get a non-null ExtendedErrorInformation. However if I try and fetch attributes of a blob which does not exist in the blob container, I will get a null ExtendedErrorInformation object. I guess one can't just assume that ExtendedErrorInformation object will always be available.

<del>Also I noticed that in your code for 2.0, you're using StorageErrorCodeStrings. Please note that it is removed from 2.0 and is available only available with version 1.8 or before. Thought I should mention that</del>

Update: Please see comment below from @VollmonD. This has been added in version 2.0.3.

Comment: StorageErrorCodeStrings has been added in 2.0.3, I got the packages via nuget. The FetchAttributes is one of the situations where I got the problem. Now I'm trying to see if I can use the error code strings to get the error message and compare it to the HttpStatus. Thank you for your blog entry, it helped me a lot during these migration days :)

Comment: My bad! I didn't know that the storage team included this back. I need to go back and update the post on exception handling :). I'm glad you liked my blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but if you are trying to handle deleting items from the blob or just checking if they exist (extension method kinda approach).
you can now use:

- CloudBlob.DeleteIfExistsAsync() - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.deleteifexistsasync.aspx
- CloudBlob.ExistsAsync() - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt423366.aspx

Check here for a list of methods on CloudBlob: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.aspx